# XML Deserialization - find specific occurrence within set maxOccurs

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize xml into a complex POCO, and the result of using xsd.exe to make my c# classes from the xsd made some properties string arrays.  That might work with my postgres db, but it doesn't work with a mocked dbcontext for unit testing.

An example XML might look like this:

`<Car>
     <CarWindow>FrontLeft</CarWindow>
     <CarWindow>BackLeft</CarWindow>
     <OtherFields></OtherFields>
</Car>`

So what I want to do is change some of these string arrays, which have a low maxOccurs of 2-4 into dedicated columns.  That change will be useful in other ways for this project too.  So instead of `string[] CarWindow` I could have `string CarWindow1; string CarWindow2`

What I'm missing is a way to specify in the XmlElement attribute a way to map the first, second, etc occurrence of a repeating element.  Something like `[XmlElement(Occurrence=1)]`

I've looked at the XmlElementAttribute documentation and maybe I'm missing it, but I don't see a way to specifically map the nth occurrence of a repeating xml node to one property.  Thanks!

Comment: If car windows a class or a string?  If it is a class you can have a base class CarWindow with inherited classes CarWindow1 and CarWindow2.  You can also do this parsing with Xml Linq instead of using deserialization.

Comment: It's just a string, and I want to use deserialization because the tree of POCO's is quite large.

Comment: I usually modify the get/set and make custom code in the get/set. This way I can keep most the the classes unchanged and then customize only some of the properties.  If you post the serialize classes for the car and the car xml then you do not have to post everything.

Comment: There's nothing like that built into `XmlSerializer` or `DataContractSerializer`.  See: [MaxOccurs Attribute Binding Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/d3hx2s7e(v=vs.100)).